# Path на Яндекс Картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, gps

Вопрос очень простой. Если построить на Яндекс Картах [маршрут](https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?ll=37.623415%2C55.753410&mode=routes&rtext=55.754875%2C37.618563~55.751103%2C37.624164&rtt=pd&ruri=~&z=15.58), то в разметке страницы этот маршрут отображается в виде массива точек в элементе path. Например вот так:

```
<path data-feature-id="6db527c7-4955-4e97-9293-57b9bfaae171" 
d="M-168.45305726397783,-80.19317288976163 
L-58.429397977888584,13.81483456818387 
L-34.68178581260145,42.93378853611648 
L-33.431911488762125,51.86024675099179 
L-20.03048123163171,87.19638187251985 
L15.590937017928809,122.83979402994737 
L14.792406198568642,133.79742018226534 
L15.174312241841108,136.69071758305654 
L16.771373879164457,135.95200368529186 
L18.40315424767323,152.75768839288503 
L26.006556388689205,152.01897945906967" 
stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="8.000" stroke-dasharray=""></path>
```

Какой алгоритм преобразования этого массива в набор точек с географическими координатами широты и долготы. Может есть ссылка на документацию карт где описан этот формат?

Comment: Это ж и есть координаты GPS

Comment: @nightflash это путь проложенный в Москве. У Москвы широта 55 и долгота 37. Что тогда значат в массиве значения вроде этих `L15.590937017928809,122.83979402994737 `

Comment: Понял, что вы смотрите. Это SVG графика. И соответственно это координаты объектов в каждом тайле на карте. В этом легко убедиться, если начать менять эти координаты - очертания домов начинают меняться.

Comment: @nightflash если вы знаете как из карт в браузере получить именно набор точек (широта, долгота) соответствующих проложенному маршруту - то расскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Используйте API, оно для этого и существует. Нет смысла парсить карты.

Comment: @nightflash мне в данный момент просто пару маршрутов надо получить в тестовых целях. Пока мне не надо использовать API. Если прямо на карте это невозможно - то да, вы правы, я поступлю именно так.

Comment: По карте не получится. Только через API. Второй вариант (если есть возможность, время, да и полезно) - пройтись по этому маршруту, а потом вытащить из истории перемещений в гугле.